# Gas price limit in metamask Rinkeby

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, gas-price, rinkeby

```
Unknown processing time 
Max fee:0ETH
```

This error occurs while testing a front end application with smart contract.

code :-

```
//this is deposit function
  function Depoist(){
    var depAmt = document.getElementById("deptAmt").value;
    web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(account){
        var acc = account[0];
        contract.methods.depoist(depAmt).send({from : acc, maxPriorityFeePerGas: null,
    maxFeePerGas: null}).then(function(tx){
            alert(tx);
        }).catch(function(err){
            swal("Oops",err);
        })
    })
```

While calling this deposit function from the front end there's a gas price error in Metamask.

[image: .]

---

same issue . See in Photo code and issue in meta mask . Please give solution

[image]

---

[image: code here]

code of deposit and withdraw . i had changed networks but not working .

Comment: What does the function `deposit` do? Can you provide the contract source code?

Comment: function depoist(uint amt) public  {
 require(amt > 0,"Depoist amt must greater than Zero");


     balance[msg.sender] += amt;

 numCustomer.push(payable(msg.sender));

 }

Answer (score 0):

You should provide proper amount of gasPrice. And if you're to send some Eth values to the contract, you should also provide the value like below.

Below code with gasPrice 400000 might work, but you'd better calculate it with your transaction for an accurate gas price value.

```
web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function (account) {
    var acc = account[0];
    contract.methods.depoist().send({
        from: acc,
        to: <YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS>,
        value: <DEPOSIT_AMOUNT_IN_WEI>,
        gasPrice: 400000,
    }).then(function (tx) {
        alert(tx);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        swal("Oops", err);
    })
})
```

Comment: same issue please above answer and give some solution.